# Sampling distribution output does not look like a continuous function

Tags: algorithms, sampling

I made a random distribution using 2 dice rolls, the output usually collects most data around mean:

[image]

Then I try to do sampling of N sample size. While using sample size of N = 2 it looks more or less real when sampling size is 3 and above it generates really strange results:

[image]
*Sample size = 5*

It does look real a little bit but not those sudden drops. I don't understand where they are coming from.

Algorithm. 
Well, it's sampling. I just brute force it. It finds every possible combination of values with a recursive function and after that calculates the mean of those. So it will be:

- [1,1,1] = mean of values is (1+1+1)/3=1 and mean of probabilities
  will be something like (0.2+0.2+0.2)/3
- [1,1,2] = (1+1+2)/3 | (0.2+0.2+0.3)/3
- ...
- [3,3,3]

Then if there are multiple results where mean values are the same it will find also mean of those. So [1,1,2] and [2,1,1] will have the same mean so their probability means will be calculated (p1+...+pn)/n. After that, the array is sorted and the output is on the second figure.

I think my issue is somewhere at the end. Combining values of the same mean seem odd to me, but I don't understand why. Any idea of what I am possibly doing wrong?

Comment: You clearly have an error in your strategy.  The distribution of values in this case has been known from the 17th century.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork I am working on this completely by myself. It looks pretty easy, that's why it seems so insane to have such issues. I need someone to share an algorithm for this, I am clearly stuck. Or point out an issue in my algorithm.

Comment: Every combination of values is trivial.  Your algorithm clearly doesn't calculate the proper *frequency* of such values... that 5 $1$s is far rarer than 2 $2$s, 2 $3$s and a $4$, to take just one of a large number of examples.

Comment: What do the $x$-axes on your graphs represent? Where did $(0.2+0.2+0.2)/3$ come from? It is entirely unclear to me what your goal is.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork It does calculate the frequency, but when it finds similar values it finds their mean. I think that's the issue. So it will do something like this: (average([2,2,3,3,4])+average([4,3,3,2,2]))/2.

Comment: @Mike Earnest x-axes are sums of results on sides of 2 dices in this example. In this exact case, there were 10 sides on each dice (0-9). y-axis is a probability of that sum to happen based on the quick simulation. The total sum of all probabilities is equal to 1. (0.2+0.2+0.2)/3 was just an example. 0.2, in this example, is a probability of sum equal to 1 and 3 is sample size.

Comment: @MikeEarnest And my goal is to do sampling on any input distribution. It doesn't matter what the input is, it does matter why the output isn't becoming any closer to a normal distribution by increasing the sample size.

Comment: Why do you seem to have points on your second graph whose $x$-values are not whole numbers? I thought the $x$-axis represented the sum of dice rolls, which should be whole numbers (integers).

Comment: Anyway, to find desired probabilities, you can essentially brute force all possibilities and *keep track of counts of each possible sum* as you go. At the end, divide the counts by the total number of possibilities (which is the sum of the counts) to obtain probabilities.

Comment: @MinusOne-Twelfth but what do I do when I get a combination of, for example, [1 2 2]? The average for these sums will be 5/3, that's why the second graph isn't just whole numbers. Or am I thinking this wrong?

Comment: I thought you were wanting to look at the distribution of the sum of dice rolls.

Comment: @MinusOne-Twelfth I do, but how does sampling work then? What do I do in the situation I described above? I do need to go through all the combinations.

Comment: You'd just look at the sum, rather than the average (so don't divide by 3). And keep count of how many times you get each distinct sum value you encounter.